# ¿Como depurar archivos .xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

he descompilado el ejecutable de una aplicación un poco antigua con el fin de recuperar los fuentes. Se trata de una aplicación WPF hecha con VS2010.

La descompilación es relativamente fácil con las herramientas disponibles pero la recompilación requiere su tiempo y un cierto nivel de conocimientos,  no obstante esta recompilación la tengo bastante avanzada. Todos los archivos ".cs" los he depurado.

Para completar la recompilación necesito depurar los archivos ".xaml", pero no puedo cargar los diseños para corregirlos. He buscado información por los foros pero esta depuración puede ser engorrosa con mi nivel de conocimientos.
¿Alguien sería tan amable de orientarme en la depuración de estos archivos, sin tener que usar el depurador de Visual Studio, si eso fuera posible, ya que no domino bien ese depurador?
Los errores son estos:

> App.xaml(5,4): error MC3073: el atributo 'Freeze' no existe en el
>   espacio de nombres XML 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'.
>   Línea 5, posición 4. About.xaml(18,5): error MC3074: la etiqueta
>   'ImageSource' no existe en el espacio de nombres XML
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation'. Línea 18,
>   posición 5. themes\classic.xaml(6,3): error MC3074: la etiqueta
>   'SolidColorBrush' no existe en el espacio de nombres XML
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation'. Línea 6,
>   posición 3. themes\expressiondark.xaml(2,3): error MC3074: la etiqueta
>   'SolidColorBrush' no existe en el espacio de nombres XML
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation'. Línea 2,
>   posición 3. themes\expressionlight.xaml(2,3): error MC3074: la
>   etiqueta 'SolidColorBrush' no existe en el espacio de nombres XML
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation'. Línea 2,
>   posición 3.

Gracias anticipadas por vuestra ayuda.
Isidro Padilla

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿Tienes referenciado WindowsBase?

Comment: Sí,lo tengo referenciado.